# JDBC,Vertx, Postgresql Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection, vert.x

```
août 09, 2018 11:38:12 AM com.mchange.v2.log.MLog 
INFOS: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
août 09, 2018 11:38:13 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry 
INFOS: Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
août 09, 2018 11:38:14 AM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource 
INFOS: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 2w77uv9x8c63hi1774dbr|1a2c4b3d, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> org.postgresql.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 2w77uv9x8c63hi1774dbr|1a2c4b3d, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/morpho_user, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 30, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7227a4e9 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ce ResultSet est fermé.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@18dab8f5 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ce ResultSet est fermé.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3920fb0f -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ce ResultSet est fermé.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7c2232a9 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7c2232a9 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool 
AVERTISSEMENT: Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7c2232a9 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
août 09, 2018 11:38:44 AM dkt.morpho.api.verticle.UserData
GRAVE: Could not open a database connection
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCClientImpl.lambda$getConnection$3(JDBCClientImpl.java:197)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ce ResultSet est fermé.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:240)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

My Vertx programm cannot connect to my postgresql database, this is the method use to get connection.

```
public Future<Void> prepareDatabase() {
    Future<Void> future = Future.future();

    dbConfig = config().getJsonObject("database").getJsonObject("db-main");
    dbClient = JDBCClient.createNonShared(vertx, dbConfig);

    dbClient.getConnection(asyncResult -> {
        if (asyncResult.failed()) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not open a database connection", asyncResult.cause());
            future.fail(asyncResult.cause());
        }
        else {
            future.complete();
        }
    });

    return future;
}
```

I follow this example : https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/
My configuration is

```
{
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname",
    "driver_class": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    "max_pool_size": 30,
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "psswd"
}
```

My pg_hba.conf is

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Have you got an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver are you using? Which version of PostgreSQL? Which version of c3p0?

Comment: The fact you get a "result set is closed" error when it is getting the transaction isolation level either indicates something is very wrong with the driver or database, or maybe this is a problem with a connection being used concurrently in an incorrect way.

Comment: I use theses versions, postgresql 10.4-1, jdbc client 3.5.3, and driver 9.1-901-1.jdbc4

Comment: Why are you using the ancient 9.1-901 JDBC driver? The latest version is 42.2.4. I'd first try that newer version of the JDBC driver, it is possible that will fix your problem. I'm not sure what "jdbc client 3.5.3" is, I asked for the c3p0 version you use.

Comment: Okay the lastest version solve my problem, i've install from maven the first version what i've seen to be honest

Comment: It is always a good idea to check if you are using the latest version of a dependency, when adding a new dependency always choose the latest (you can check - for example - on https://search.maven.org/, there are also tools/plugins that will help with this). When upgrading it is usually advisable to keep up and upgrade (but this is not always the best choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver (9.1-901), and either it has a bug, or you run into a compatibility issues with PostgreSQL 10 (which was released years after the release of the JDBC 9.1 driver). You need to upgrade to the latest version of the driver, 42.2.4.

Comment: Note: I just posted this to formalize the solution hashed out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You should try to get an updated PostgreSQL JDBC Connector. I tried to connect to PostgreSQL 11 with an old Connector and it failed with the same error. I updated the connector in my project and it worked!!!!